# Which version of patch-release to build?

Tags: wso2

The release matrix for the wso2 platform is here: http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/

If I want to build Identity Server 4.0.0 it seems that I need carbon 4.0.3.

**Question 1.** Will Identity Server only build on carbon 4.0.3, or will it build on 4.0.3+?

I have checked out the source from:

https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/orbit/branches/4.0.0
https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.0.0
https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0

However, when I look in the orbit patch-releases folder, I only see:

```
4.0.1  
4.0.2  
4.0.5  
4.0.6
```

**Question 2**. Which version of orbit patch release will I need to build for IS 4.0.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 01**

To build IS 4.0.0 you need to build patch-release 4.0.3
But there can be some components from 4.0.0 up-to 4.0.3 but not 4.0.3+ So its better to build all main branch plus patch-release versions below your required version. As Ratha mentioned if you build online these jars will be downloaded if available.

**Question 02**

You need to build orbit patch-release 4.0.2 since it was used on IS 4.0.0
The reason for not having patch-release 4.0.3 version is there is no difference from 4.0.2 version. So same version is used during production.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't find particular version, that means product is released with older version of jars..
In your case, you might need to build 4.0.2..
Anyway if you do online build, if jars are available in the repo, they will be downloaded..You don't need to build older versions..
If not, you have to..